# Google map get current floor

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using new Google map in my android application. I have different floors in my building. I need to get current floor.

Comment: Please provide more information, what have you tried? And can you show some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A while ago you asked... today I found a solution. First of all, you need the latest google-play-services_lib (v4.4). In Eclipse, update Play Services via the SDK Manager and follow the [Setup](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html). Then you need to implement the [OnIndoorStateChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnIndoorStateChangeListener.html) in your activity. Don't forget to to set your activity as listener to your GoogleMap. E.g:

```
public class YourActivity implements OnIndoorStateChangeListener {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...
      yourGoogleMap.setOnIndoorStateChangeListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onIndoorLevelActivated(IndoorBuilding indoorBuilding) {
      List<IndoorLevel> levels = indoorBuilding.getLevels();
      for (IndoorLevel indoorLevel : levels) {
         indoorLevel.get...
      }
   }
```

When you have a building with indoor information on your map you receive a `IndoorBuilding` object via callback. From this `IndoorBuilding` you can get a list of `IndoorLevels` and inside the `IndoorLevel` you find a few getters.

When you call `indoorBuilding.getActiveLevelIndex()`, GoogleMaps counts from the roof to the basement - the same direction you iterate over the `IndoorLevel` list. This means, that you could find the maximum level index six feet under.

Hope, this helps!

UPDATE: I found a better solution...

```
IndoorBuilding yourBuilding = yourGoogleMap.getFocusedBuilding();
List<IndoorLevel> levels = yourBuilding.getLevels();
String name = levels.get(yourBuilding.getActiveLevelIndex()).getName();
String shortName = levels.get(yourBuilding.getActiveLevelIndex()).getShortName();
```